# how do I implement a custom code page used by a serial device so I can convert text to it in Python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf

I have a scrolling LED sign that takes messages in either ASCII or (using some specific code) characters from a custom code page.

For example, the euro sign should be sent as

```
<U00>
```

and ä is

```
<U64>
```

(You can find the full code page in the [documentation](http://www.domoticaforum.eu/uploaded/Jfn/20082291593_RGB%20ledbar%20conrad.pdf))

My question is, what is the most pythonic way to implement this custom code page, and to have a codec that can convert UTF strings to my custom code page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Pick a name for your encoding, maybe "led_display", whatever.
2. Implement and register a [codec](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html) with the standard library.
3. Pythonic profit!